# angularjs : Reload a controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have a controller I am calling an API on MVC.
This API returns me back a partial view, This partial view is associated with my controller from which I am calling the API .

Now as soon as I getting the partial view back, I am vanishing the html of the view and then re-rendering the view.

but my controller method never get initated, I guess because the controller is already initiated.

Question is can I call method of controller when it loads back.

html :

```
<div id="pageholder">
            <-- here is my view , which I am changing thru API , and I want to re render it, and also want to perform certain controller methods -->
            </div>
```

ANGULAR :

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {
        config: item,
        parameter: itemParametrs
    }

}).success(function(data, status) {
    $('#pageholder').empty();
    $scope.username="username";
    $('#pageholder').html(data);
});
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: to render the html you can call $apply since you're not using angular directives to manipulate the DOM it does not get called.. to rerender the controller you can either have a function that calls some init function meaning after success just call your init function... or I guess you could refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile that new HTML you get. No directive or controller will be watched by Angular if you dynamically write HTML:

```
.success(function(data, status) {
  $scope.username="username";

  var $pholder = $('#pageholder');
  $pholder.empty();
  $pholder.html(data);

  // Recompile the HTML so angular can process it
  $compile($pholder)($scope);
});
```

PS: you will need to get the `$compile` service in your directive/controller (the same way you get `$http`)